# A word for 'the ability to see beauty'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In talking about someone, perhaps an artist, who has the ability to find or see beautiful things in everyday settings. Is there a word for it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best is

> aesthete
>   a person who is appreciative of and sensitive to art and beauty.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define=aesthete)

So the trait is *"aestheticism"*.

<sup>Found with the help of [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/), [with their the reverse search](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml), by searching [*"one who sees beauty in everyday objects"*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=one%20who%20sees%20beauty%20in%20everyday%20objects)</sup>

Comment: So the character trait is aestheticism n ...
2. sensitivity to beauty, esp in art, music, literature, etc [Collins]

Comment: Yeah, thats it I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply, ***eye*** has this meaning.

Though, it is mainly used in the idiom ***to have an eye for something***.

> the faculty of intellectual or aesthetic perception or appreciation
>
> *an eye for beauty*
>
> [[merriam-webster]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye)

---

As a general word, you can use ***appreciation***.

> Awareness or delicate perception, especially of aesthetic qualities or values.
>
> [[thefreedictionary]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appreciation)

Answer (score 0):

philocalist - lover of beauty; one who sees beauty in all things

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

In a word, **imagine** should suffice.